# Error during registration: RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, bots

I have developed a Python script for creating SoundCloud accounts using Firefox Selenium WebDriver. This script automates the registration process on the SoundCloud website, including solving the sliding puzzle captcha using the 2Captcha service. The script is designed to automate the process of registering a SoundCloud account, including the handling of the funcaptcha sliding puzzle captcha challenge using the 2Captcha service. It uses the Selenium WebDriver for browser automation and the BeautifulSoup library for web scraping.

2Captcha Integration:

The script starts by importing the necessary libraries and defining your 2Captcha API key.
It includes a function called solve_puzzle_captcha, which takes the WebDriver instance and your API key as arguments.
This function sends a request to the 2Captcha API with the URL of the captcha image and retrieves the captcha solution using a polling mechanism.
SoundCloud Registration:

Another function called register_soundcloud handles the SoundCloud registration process.
It opens the SoundCloud homepage, scrolls down to make the "Sign in" button visible, and clicks it.
After that, it waits for the registration form to load and inputs your email address.
It then proceeds to the "Choose a password" page, where it enters your chosen password.
The script extracts the captcha image URL from the page source and utilizes the solve_puzzle_captcha function to obtain the captcha solution.
The solution is input into the captcha field, and finally, the "Continue" button is clicked to complete the registration.
WebDriver Configuration:

The script configures the WebDriver by specifying the path to the GeckoDriver executable (you need to replace this path with the location of your GeckoDriver executable).
It initializes the WebDriver with this configuration and then calls the registration function.

Tried getting the user data into the page with the elements being located, but I keep getting this error

C:\Users\austin\Downloads\soundcloud\import3.py:106: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_driver_path)

Error during registration: Message:
Stacktrace:

> RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
> WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:188:5
> NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:506:5
> dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:132:16
>
> Double-checked that the element locators (e.g., CSS selectors, XPaths)
> are accurate & have updated browser and drivers

`````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 2Captcha API key
api_key = 'YOUR_2CAPTCHA_API_KEY'

# Function to solve the sliding puzzle captcha using 2Captcha
def solve_puzzle_captcha(driver, api_key):
    # Replace 'captcha_image_url' with the actual URL of the captcha image
    captcha_image_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/captcha_image_url'

    try:
        # Send a request to 2Captcha API
        response = requests.post(
            f'http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={api_key}&method=funcaptcha&json=1&url={captcha_image_url}'
        )

        if response.status_code == 200:
            captcha_response = response.json()
            if captcha_response['status'] == 1:
                captcha_id = captcha_response['request']
                # Poll 2Captcha for the captcha solution (you may need to implement a loop)
                solution_response = None
                while solution_response is None or solution_response['status'] != 1:
                    time.sleep(5)  # Polling interval
                    solution_response = requests.get(
                        f'http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={api_key}&action=get&id={captcha_id}&json=1'
                    ).json()
                captcha_solution = solution_response['request']
                return captcha_solution
            else:
                print('2Captcha request failed:', captcha_response)
        else:
            print('2Captcha request failed with status code', response.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error during 2Captcha solving:', e)
    return None

# Function to perform the SoundCloud registration process
def register_soundcloud(driver):
    try:
        # Open SoundCloud homepage
        driver.get('https://soundcloud.com')

        # Scroll down to make the "Sign in" button visible
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Click the "Sign in" button and wait for the registration link to load
        sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Sign in']"))
        )
        sign_in_button.click()

        # Wait for the registration form to load
        time.sleep(2)

        # Input email
        email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.sc-input[name='email']"))
        )
        email_field.send_keys('your@email.com')
        continue_button_1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sign_in_up_submit')
        continue_button_1.click()

        # Wait for the "Choose a password" page to load
        time.sleep(2)

        # Input your password and click "Continue"
        password_field = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        password_field.send_keys('your_password')
        continue_button_2 = driver.find_element_by_id('enter_password_submit')
        continue_button_2.click()

        # Wait for the additional information page to load
        time.sleep(2)

        # Extract the captcha image URL
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        captcha_image = soup.find('img', {'class': 'captcha-image'})
        captcha_image_url = captcha_image['src']

        # Solve the captcha and input the solution
        captcha_solution = solve_puzzle_captcha(driver, api_key)
        if captcha_solution:
            captcha_input_field = driver.find_element_by_id('captcha_response_field')
            captcha_input_field.send_keys(captcha_solution)

            # Click "Continue" to complete registration
            continue_button_3 = driver.find_element_by_id('submit_signup')
            continue_button_3.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error during registration:', e)

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

# Configure the WebDriver
gecko_driver_path = r'C:\Users\austin\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'  # Replace with your GeckoDriver path
service = webdriver.firefox.service.Service(gecko_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_driver_path)

# Call the registration function
solve_puzzle_captcha(driver, api_key)
register_soundcloud(driver)````
`````